# If statement in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a game, and a *MySQL* database table where I store the results of users. Every result is stored, but on highscore page I show only the best result from a certain user, like this:

```
SELECT user_id,MAX(score) as score 
FROM   table 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT $startLimit,$numPerPage
```

But now I also want to make it relate to time it took for player to reach certain score, if the scores are level.

For example **if** the player has two same scores, I want to grab the one that took him less time (ofcourse there is a column "time" in this table).

Comment: `SELECT user_id,MAX(score),Min(Time) as score FROM table GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT $startLimit,$numPerPage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id,score,MIN(time) as MinTime
FROM
(SELECT user_id,MAX(score) as score,time
FROM table 
GROUP BY user_id, time ) T
GROUP BY user_id,score
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT $startLimit,$numPerPage
```

It will return the records with minimum time if the user has same score.

Comment: This doesn't work.

If I have user with ID 1 that made score of 11 in 5 seconds, and another score of 10 in 2 seconds, that would return me the score of 11 and time of 2 seconds which isn't right.